# How do I store the attributes of a HTML file based on the requirements configured in a filter file in an XML output file?

Tags: perl, file-io

I want to write a Perl script which seems easy but somehow I am lost in it.

I have a HTML file and a `filter.txt` file.

HTML file has contents like

```
<tr><td>DATA_START</td><td align="center">77777</td><td align="center">0</td><td align="center">0</td></tr>.....
```

I want to search the contents of the file `filter.txt`. If there is that content, then get its attribute A and B. In this case, if `DATA_start` is part of `filter.txt` and its there in the HTML file, then A is 7777 and B is 0.

This result I want to put in an XML file.

Comment: What does the filter file look like? What is the XML output supposed to look like? What have you tried, which problems have you encountered exactly, at which step are you stuck without help? The question is incomplete without this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open filter.txt and the slurp HTML file to a scalar. Then grep the html for the pattern, and use a simple regexp to parse the line.

Beware, this works only this HTML stucture, not rock solid solution. Use Marpa for more robust approach.

```
use Data::Dumper;
$html =~ s#\s*</tr>\s*#</tr>\n#gis;
$html =~ s#\s*<tr[^>]*>\s*#\n<tr>#gis;
while(<FILTER>){
  my $pattern = $_;
  my @datalines = grep {/$pattern/} $html;
  foreach my $dataline (@datalines){
     my (@data) = $dataline =~ m#<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td>#gis;
     die Dumper(@data,$dataline);
  }
}
```